# get data from webhook telegram bot with node js

Tags: node.js, https, async-await, telegram-bot, webhooks

I set the server address for the bot with `/setwebhook`, now how can I get the data with **only node js and https** package to access {message :{...} }? (like `/getupdates` method) but by webhook , probably I mean like the php code but in node js: `file_get_contents("php://input")` .
Should I use `async` or `https.createServer` ?  If yes, how and please explain a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a server that will handle receiving the data. You can do this by using `http.createServer` or, more conveniently, using a library such as [Express](http://expressjs.com/). Simple implementation using Express would look like this:

```js
const app = express();

app.post(`/api/telegram${process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}`, async (req, res) => {
    
    const message = req.body.message || req.body.edited_message;
    ...
});
```

In this example, I use bot token in the webhook url (since I and Telegram are the only entities that know the bot token, I can be sure that the requests to the url come from Telegram). There are better ways to make the webhook secure, such as using `secret_token` as specified in the docs for [setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) method.

For development purposes, you can use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to redirect requests from the bot webhook to localhost.

*To get an idea of a fully functioning example of implementing webhook with node.js and Express, you can check my open-source [project](https://github.com/druskacik/binance-staking-notification-bot/blob/master/backend/src/routes/webhooks/telegram/index.js) on Github.*